# Trying to use a function to write a matrix into a file in C

Tags: c

I want to make a program that writes a random (from numbers 0-100) 5x5 matrix into a file. I know how to make a matrix but I am not sure how to put it into a file. I've been trying to use a function but don't exactly know how to formalize it. Also I think I need to change the output1 function into a int function but I have no clue how to do it. I hope someone can help! Thanks.
Here's the code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#define maxA 5
#define maxB 5
int tabel1[maxA][maxB];
int a, b;
void input1() {
    a = 5;
    b = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            tabel1[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}
void output1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            printf("%d    ", tabel1[i][j]); 
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
void  writeFile()
{
    int output1();
    char    tabel1[5][5];
    FILE    *fptr;
    int     i;
    int     num;
    char    num2;
    i = 0;

    fptr = fopen("ticket.txt", "w");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR Creating File!");
        exit(1);
    }
     srand((unsigned)time(0));
    
    fprintf(fptr, "%d", output1());
}
int main(){
    
    writeFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. Compile your file `rasmus.c` as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g rasmus.c -o rasmus` to get all warnings and debug info. Your last use of `fprintf` is wrong. Imprtove your C code to get no warnings, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable. Check on [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) how to use *every function you did not define*, notably `fprintf`

Comment: In addition to @BasileStarynkevitch I would suggest you use an IDE which makes debugging easier.

Comment: The source code editor could be [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) which can run GCC and GDB. I don't understand how an IDE makes debugging easier (it is GDB which is the debugger)

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a file using `fprintf()`. Also, you had not called `input1()` function in your code, so I called it in `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define maxA 5
#define maxB 5
int tabel1[maxA][maxB];
int a, b;
void input1() {
    a = 5;
    b = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            tabel1[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}
void output1(FILE    *fptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            fprintf(fptr, "%d    ", tabel1[i][j]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            fprintf(fptr, "\n");
        }
    }
}
void  writeFile()
{
    char    tabel1[5][5];
    FILE    *fptr;
    int     i;
    int     num;
    char    num2;
    i = 0;

    fptr = fopen("ticket.txt", "w");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR Creating File!");
        exit(1);
    }
    output1(fptr);
}
int main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    input1();
    writeFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I open the ticket.txt file it still displays only a 0, what's the problem? But thanks for posting.

Comment: @Rasmus Can you try now? I changed `cstdio` and `ctime` to `stdio.h` and `time.h` respectively.

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason it still doesn't work but is it working for you?

Comment: Yes. For me it is working perfectly fine. I am getting 5 rows in the file.

Comment: Can I ask what compiler you're using?

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)

Comment: Are you opening the correct file? Delete the file "ticket.txt". Run the code, a new file will be created in the same directory of this code. Open this new file and check.

Comment: I deleted the file but it works in online compilers but not in the one I'm using (dev cpp). Also the process seems to take much shorter time than usual.